# Getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keyboard,'

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-ide

After installing white library in robot framework, and running 'press special key' F12 keyword getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keyboard'.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you provide us with some verifiable example, a code snippet, a traceback, anything that will help checking what's wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I installed whitelibrary in robot framework and in RIDE i have entered the keyword

Press special key    F12

But i m getting attribute error as nontype

Comment: Please show the actual code that you're using as part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to select the window first where the keypress is going. This happens with either "Select Modal Window"  or "Attach Window" keywords.  Error you get indicates that internal state "self.state.Window" has not be set and thus you NoneType exception.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you :)